# References on a certain generalization of Dedekind groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

Recall that a group is called a [*Dedekind group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group) if all of its subgroups
are normal. Also recall that a weaker property of a subgroup than normality
is that of being a [*TI-subgroup*](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/TI-subgroup): a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called
a *TI-subgroup* if for every $g \in G$ it is $H \cap H^g \in \{1,H\}$.

The groups all of whose subgroups are TI-subgroups have been classified in:

G. Walls: [*Trivial intersection groups*](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0388.20011), Arch. Math. 32, 1-4 (1979).

Now it is natural to weaken the condition to a certain extent, and to consider
groups a certain subset of whose subgroups are TI-subgroups. --
So for example the groups all of whose abelian subgroups are TI-subgroups are
classified in:

Guo, Xiuyun; Li, Shirong; Flavell, Paul: [*Finite groups whose Abelian
subgroups are TI-subgroups*](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1116.20014), J. Algebra 307, No. 2, 565-569 (2007).

**Question:** Is anyone aware of any work having been done so far on groups
the derived subgroups of all of whose subgroups are TI-subgroups?

Comment: What is your motivation to choose subgroups of derived subgroup?

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi: Not subgroups of the derived subgroup -- but subgroups which occur as derived subgroups of subgroups (as written in the question).

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi: My collaborator Leyli Jafari suggested the topic, and the aim of the question is to find out whether anyone else has already done some work on these groups, in order to avoid duplicating existing work.

Comment: @StefaKohl  I misunderstood the question. Anyway, interesting to know why she did not choose another subgroup instead of the derived subgroup?