# Are there perfect DTI-groups which are not simple?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Recall that a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called a [*TI-subgroup*](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/TI-subgroup)
if for every $g \in G$ it is $H \cap H^g \in \{1,H\}$.
We say that a group $G$ is a DTI-group if the derived subgroups of all
of its subgroups are TI-subgroups.

*Question:* Is it true that a non-trivial finite perfect DTI-group
is necessarily simple?

*Remark:* I know that -- provided that it exists -- a non-trivial finite
non-simple perfect DTI-group necessarily is minimal non-solvable.

*Related question:* [References on a certain generalization of Dedekind groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309503/)

Comment: I was wondering whether the non-split version of $2^3.GL_3(2)$ might be a potential candidate. do you have an easy way to test this?

Comment: @NickGill Running a check over the perfect groups of order less than about 50000 with GAP did not reveal a non-simple perfect DTI-group. -- So any counterexample (if it exists!) must be bigger.